# How do I check the version of IDL I am using?

Tags: linux, idl-programming-language

## Background

According to [L3Harris](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Support/Self-Help-Tools/Help-Articles/Help-Articles-Detail/ArtMID/10220/ArticleID/15313/How-to-determine-the-product-version-of-IDL-ENVI-and-Exelis-Products-FlexLM-License-Server-installed-on-a-computer-system), to check the version of IDL you are using, you have to check the /usr/local/ directory as follows:

> Linux, Solaris, Mac OS X
>
> On Linux, Solaris and Mac, you can determine the base product version
> installed through the name of the associated main IDL or ENVI product
> directory installed the machine.
>
> On these platforms, the default product installation location depends
> on the version of IDL, ENVI associated with that product. Below are
> the default main product directories for IDL and corresponding ENVI
> products going back to IDL 8.0 and ENVI 4.8. The Exelis Products
> FlexLM License Server product version corresponds to the IDL version
> included with the installation.
>
> Linux, Solaris    Mac OS X IDL    ENVI    IDL ENVI /usr/local/exelis/idl85
> /usr/local/exelis/envi53 /Applications/exelis/idl85
> /Applications/exelis/envi53 usr/local/exelis/idl84
> /usr/local/exelis/envi52 /Applications/exelis/idl84
> /Applications/exelis/envi52 /usr/local/exelis/idl83
> /usr/local/exelis/envi51 /Applications/exelis/idl83
> /Applications/exelis/envi51 /usr/local/exelis/idl82
> /usr/local/exelis/envi50 /Applications/exelis/idl82
> /Applications/exelis/envi50 /usr/local/itt/idl/idl81
> -- n/a -- /Applications/itt/idl/idl81
> -- n/a -- /usr/local/itt/idl/idl80 //usr/local/itt/envi/envi48 /Applications/itt/idl/idl80 /Applications/itt/idl/idl80

Unfortunately I have none of the directories specified here.  My `/usr/local/` directory structure looks like the following:

> /usr/local
> > ls
>
> /bin  /etc  /games  /gcc-6.1.0  /include  /lib  /lib64  /libexec  /sbin  /share  /src

And a recursive ls with a grep for idl turns up nothing:

[image]

## Question

Where is the documenation located that described which version of IDL is installed on my system?

Comment: Can you start IDL? Do you have any idea where IDL is installed? If you can start IDL, then doing "which idl" will get you started on where IDL is located.

Comment: If you have no idea where IDL is installed and can't start it, then try "find / -name idl". It will probably take awhile.

Comment: If you can start IDL, the version will show in the banner that is printed when it starts.